# How to push system metric from one machine to another in linux using collectd?

Tags: linux, bash

I have two centos Machine, Machine A and Machine B. In machine A i have installed collectd and influxdb. So, the system metric from machine A is pushed into influxdb using collectd. I have installed collectd in machine B. Now, I need to push the system metric from machine B to the influxdb which is in machine A.

Collectd uses the port 25826. When I run the below mentioned command in Machine A my output is:

**Machine A:**

```
command: netstat -tuplen | grep ':25826'
 output : udp6       0      0 :::25826  :::* 981  325073833  23132/influxd
```

**In Machine B:**

```
sudo netstat -tuplen | grep ':25826'
```

No output came.

When i use below mentioned command in **Machine B**:

```
command:telnet "xxx.xx.xx.xx" "25826"
output:Trying xxx.xx.xx.xx...
telnet: connect to address xxx.xx.xx.xx: No route to host
```

How to create the host in machine B...So that i can push the metric from Machine B to Machine A...From both machine PING command is working

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you're just listing the listening ports using the nestat command so it would be expected that nothing would be listening on that port on Machine B. You must have a configuration you applied on Machine A. Repeat it for Machine B but use the remote? It's unclear what IP the xxx one would be.

Comment: Also could you please tell us in what networks are those two machines? Are they in the same local network and can they ping each other?

Comment: @Fanatique ya two machines can ping each other...

Comment: @ seth I copied the same conf files in Machine B as machine A...In machine B in the conf files of collectd i changed the network plugin like LoadPlugin  network
<Plugin network>
Server "<Machine A IP>" "25826"
</Plugin>